# how to access static variables using ui.xml

Tags: uibinder

I have a class with some static variables like
    public static String MENU = "menu1";
How do i access the value of those variables in ui.xml ?

To access methods i saw something like

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind a label to text in backing class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109363/how-to-bind-a-label-to-text-in-backing-class)

Answer (score 0):

I found this question and solved it somehow later.

My class holding the global shared limits

```
/**
 * Class to hold shared limits for input fields
 */
public final class InputLimits {
    /**
     * private constructor that prevent instantiation.
     */
    private InputLimits() {

    }


    public static final int MAX_LENGTH = 10;

    /**

     * @return max length for GWT (is resolved at compile time no instance of class needed only method declaration)

     */

public static final int getMaxLength() {

    return MAX_LENGTH;

    }

}
```

I'm using this in GWT in the following way:

```
<ui:with field="InputLimits" type="....InputLimits"/>
<g:TextBox ui:field="text" maxLength="{InputLimits.getMaxLength}" />
```

Official GWT documentation should be here:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Text_Resources