# How to bind a label to text in backing class?

Tags: java, gwt

How can I bind a GWT label to a string property in the backing class for the view?

```
Login.ui.xml:
Welcome <g:Label text="{textFromJavaBackingClass}" />

class Login {
  String userName;
  String getUserName() { return userName; }
}
```

How can I bind the value to `String userName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a i18n class `MyI18n` which extends `Messages`

Just include the following

```
<ui:with field="i18n" type="MyI18n"/>
```

Then

```
Welcome <g:Label text="{i18n.textFromJavaBackingClass}" />
```

Note : MyI18n is actually not required to extends `Messages`, this is just the common way to call any no-arg method.

```
<ui:with field="clazz" type="AnyClass"/>

Welcome <g:Label text="{clazz.anyMehtodWhichDoesNotTakeArgs}" />
```

Comment: Just a note: if you simply want to display text, use `<ui:text from="{clazz.methodName}"` instead using a widget (the `Label`). It could even have the chance [to get inlined](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Text_Resources).

Comment: OK I see for static resources this might be good. But imagine the following: a view that has an input field and a submit button. If the button is clicked, I want to show the value from the input field below the button in a textbox. Thus, I somehow have to dynamically bind the textbox to the value of the input field. This cannot be done the way you described, as classes that `extends Composite` cannot be used in `ui:with` declarations...

Comment: You can implement a method like `String getInputFieldValue()` and try text="{something.getInputFieldValue}"

Answer (score 1):

Declare class in xml

```
   <ui:with field="myclass" type='package.ClassName' />
```

In Ui binder  write

```
g:Label text='{myclass.getUsername}'></g:Label>
```

Here is the [reference for future](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/05/gwt-uibinder-passing-parameters-to-widgets/)

Comment: No, I mean the other way around: set the userName in the java class, and then take in in the ui-binder to display it.

Comment: I wrote a further comment above. I not looking for a way to display static resources. It should be dynamic.

Comment: You can fetch from database and then you can return value  there even . The UiBinder waits ....